# Sort for a specific key in a deeply nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have a deeply nested dictionary as such:

```
{u'1009': {u'2017': {u'April': {u'Revenue': 36087,
    u'Total_users': 107,
    u'Unique_users': 79},
   u'August': {u'Revenue': 103458, u'Total_users': 314, u'Unique_users': 208},
   u'December': {u'Revenue': 132834,
    u'Total_users': 440,
    u'Unique_users': 241},
   u'July': {u'Revenue': 98120, u'Total_users': 356, u'Unique_users': 212},
   u'June': {u'Revenue': 88315, u'Total_users': 293, u'Unique_users': 169},
   u'May': {u'Revenue': 114438, u'Total_users': 348, u'Unique_users': 203},
   u'November': {u'Revenue': 114747,
    u'Total_users': 414,
    u'Unique_users': 233},
   u'October': {u'Revenue': 114073, u'Total_users': 339, u'Unique_users': 223},
   u'September': {u'Revenue': 87587,
    u'Total_users': 290,
    u'Unique_users': 190}},
  u'2018': {u'April': {u'Revenue': 4780,
    u'Total_users': 13,
    u'Unique_users': 12},
   u'February': {u'Revenue': 99922, u'Total_users': 354, u'Unique_users': 205},
   u'January': {u'Revenue': 195031, u'Total_users': 429, u'Unique_users': 239},
   u'March': {u'Revenue': 111568, u'Total_users': 359, u'Unique_users': 222}}},
 u'1051': {u'2017': {u'August': {u'Revenue': 11700,
    u'Total_users': 40,
    u'Unique_users': 26},
   u'July': {u'Revenue': 39730, u'Total_users': 132, u'Unique_users': 42},
   u'June': {u'Revenue': 16320, u'Total_users': 54, u'Unique_users': 36},
   u'May': {u'Revenue': 47572, u'Total_users': 160, u'Unique_users': 141},
   u'September': {u'Revenue': 250, u'Total_users': 1, u'Unique_users': 1}}},
 u'1056': {u'2017': {u'August': {u'Revenue': 1426,
    u'Total_users': 6,
    u'Unique_users': 6},
   u'December': {u'Revenue': 380, u'Total_users': 2, u'Unique_users': 2},
   u'July': {u'Revenue': 6220, u'Total_users': 20, u'Unique_users': 11},
   u'June': {u'Revenue': 20370, u'Total_users': 66, u'Unique_users': 35},
   u'May': {u'Revenue': 57566, u'Total_users': 181, u'Unique_users': 127},
   u'November': {u'Revenue': 250, u'Total_users': 1, u'Unique_users': 1},
   u'October': {u'Revenue': 250, u'Total_users': 1, u'Unique_users': 1},
   u'September': {u'Revenue': 1000, u'Total_users': 3, u'Unique_users': 3}},
  u'2018': {u'April': {u'Revenue': 4440,
    u'Total_users': 12,
    u'Unique_users': 5},
   u'February': {u'Revenue': 26149, u'Total_users': 74, u'Unique_users': 26},
   u'January': {u'Revenue': 92050, u'Total_users': 310, u'Unique_users': 204},
   u'March': {u'Revenue': 16548, u'Total_users': 55, u'Unique_users': 33}}},
 u'1103': {u'2017': {u'August': {u'Revenue': 42050,
    u'Total_users': 104,
    u'Unique_users': 52},
   u'December': {u'Revenue': 24319, u'Total_users': 76, u'Unique_users': 48},
   u'July': {u'Revenue': 27160, u'Total_users': 92, u'Unique_users': 40},
   u'June': {u'Revenue': 28470, u'Total_users': 97, u'Unique_users': 45},
   u'May': {u'Revenue': 1550, u'Total_users': 3, u'Unique_users': 3},
   u'November': {u'Revenue': 25290, u'Total_users': 90, u'Unique_users': 43},
   u'October': {u'Revenue': 17840, u'Total_users': 62, u'Unique_users': 42},
   u'September': {u'Revenue': 21800, u'Total_users': 75, u'Unique_users': 44}},
  u'2018': {u'April': {u'Revenue': 17894,
    u'Total_users': 63,
    u'Unique_users': 57},
   u'February': {u'Revenue': 147772,
    u'Total_users': 610,
    u'Unique_users': 553},
   u'January': {u'Revenue': 17549, u'Total_users': 66, u'Unique_users': 42},
   u'March': {u'Revenue': 471022,
    u'Total_users': 1898,
    u'Unique_users': 1557}}}
```

The data format is

> {'mid':{'year':{'month': { Revenue: ,,,,,}}}}

With this, for a specific year, say `2017`

I need to calculate a sorted list, of the keys by their Total Revenue(sum of all months).
like `top_5 = ['1259', '403', '1251', '1119', '1009'], bottom_5 = ['1468', '1503', '1387', '509', '1129']`.

I'm not sure how to go about this, so any headway would be helpful.

Comment: What is meant by "sorted list[names] of Revenue(sum of all months) generating mid" ? Can you be more explicit here by giving some example output you want? Actually, it would be better if you could simplify the problem and remove things specific to your variable names. It is not too hard to sort by the sum of all month's revenues, but *what* exactly do you want sorted? Like, what are the things in that sorted list?

Comment: The intent of your question is unclear. Please clarify your question. Also, explain how you want to achieve it **manually**, that would give more intuition.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what you want to achieve but without resorting to flatten nested dicts in a recursive way I would convert your dictionary to a **pandas** `dataframe` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j,k): your_dict[i][j][k] 
                           for i in your_dict.keys() 
                           for j in your_dict[i].keys()
                           for k in your_dict[i][j].keys()},
                       orient='index')
```

then you could for instance:

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().sort_values("Revenue")
```

to generate the sum for **each month** for a given **year** by your **mid** value

or you could flatten the indices by:

```
flattened_df = df.reset_index()
flattened_df.rename(columns={'level_0': 'mid', 'level_1': 'year', 'level_2': 'month'})
```

This will allow you to see what is going on with the data.

Comment: I see, but would there be any way to use for loops instead of importing pandas ?

Comment: @RagsGupta Is there any incentive to loop over the dictionary?